# Programmatically disable GPS in android >= 7 , not root or system app

Tags: android, gps

I am currently developing an application that requires blocking or disabling the use of GPS on the device, I know that there are functions from EMM with Device Police Manager, root, or system application. But the requirement is to apply it to a common user application, do you know any way to do it?
PD: "It should be noted that the idea is to disable without turning it off or on by the user, that is, asking the user to turn it off does not work, the idea is to disable the option to turn the GPS on or off"

Comment: If your app does not need gps then do not use it. Dont try to turn it off for my app that runs on the same device. And dont try to do things wirhout the user knowing it. Terrible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The app is for device administration and for a specific functionality, the user is aware that the app will block the use of GPS, the idea is that no app can use it, I know that with EMM it can be done, but the client doesn't want to use android services for work.